# CloudBoost query Invalid URI The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cloudboost

I took a look at CloudBoost today and it looked to do all the things I'm going to want for my commercial apps. The quick video tutorial showed easily how to add data to the tables in the database, and this code works fine for me, so I know that my Key and AppID are ok. However, going through the API documentation, I can't get past this point! I can't get any queries to work at all, and also a lot of the documentation contains incorrect syntax and parameters for methods which is not helpful. Here is where I'm stuck, so if anyone is using CloudBoost and has got it working C# it would be great if you could point me in the right direction. Many thanks in advance. Here's my test code.

```
        private async void Test()
    {
        CloudApp.init(AppID, Key);

        //Code to query fails
        CB.CloudQuery query = new CB.CloudQuery("tblPerson");
        query.EqualTo("name", "Davy");
        var result = await query.Find(); //Error here
    }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (C#) and the error is "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Comment: We are working on it, You could fork here if u wish to  https://github.com/CloudBoost/.net-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the .NET SDK which is fixed now. Can you please NuGet the latest version of the SDK.